# Upgrade Oracle APEX 4.0.2 to 5.1.1 error

Tags: installation, upgrade, errors, oracle-xe, oracle-apex

I installed Oracle 11g XE on CentOS 7 and everything went fine.

I wanted to upgrade APEX to the latest version and followed instructions in [Upgrading Oracle Application Express within Oracle Database 11g Express Edition (XE)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/application-express/upgrade-apex-for-xe-154969.html). Did everything that said and get following error:

> ```
> ORA-24344: success with compilation error ...
> in create_upgrade_triggers for ...
> create or replace trigger wwv_flow_upgrade_trg133 
> before insert or update or delete on WWV_PURGE_WORKSPACE_RESPONSES begin
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This is

[**Bug 25560625 : ORA-24344 ERRORS IN INSTALL.LOG THROUGH UPGRADE FROM APEX 4.0.2 TO 5.1**](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/BugDisplay?_adf.ctrl-state=1bnqbvdcyb_363&id=25560625)

Still under investigation.

You could upgrade to 4.1 and then to 5.1 to avoid this bug, or you could also try 5.0.